# What to do with generic, ambigious and not very helpful tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've just stumbled upon the SU tag [`error`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/error), which is, in my opinion, a not very helpful tag. There are at the moment 317 questions tagged with it (there were also two question tagged with `error-message`, but I removed it), and I'd say that more than 90% of the questions on SU are about errors in one way or the other.

So, is there any official policy about it, which I just didn't find? Should I remove such tags on sight, or are they 'okay'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I may point you to this [blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) about meta tags. For me, `error` falls into this category. So just raising it to attention here - which you did - might get it on the list, if there is consent about it being a meta tag.

From the blog entry:

> How can you tell you’re using a
> meta-tag? It’s easier than you might
> think.
>
> If the tag can’t work as the only tag
> on a question, it’s probably a
> meta-tag. Every tag you use should be
> able to work, more or less, as the
> only tag on a question. Meta-tags,
> like [beginner], [subjective], and
> [best-practices], are useless by
> themselves — they tell you nothing at
> all about the content of the question.
>
> If the tag commonly means different
> things to different people, it’s
> probably a meta-tag. In a cruel,
> ironic twist, the meaning of the tag
> [subjective] itself … is actually
> subjective. Ditto for [best-practices]
> and [beginner]. Best practices to
> whom? Beginner by what criteria? These
> tags are impossible to define by
> anything remotely resembling an
> objective metric. In comparison, the
> the meaning of tags like [java], [c#],
> and [javascript] are crystal clear to
> all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

Just cleaning up yourself is noble, but will not prevent from people using the tag or even creating it anew. What is necessary though is to tag questions that only use this tag, as a cleanup will render them "tag-less".

Answer (score 3):

If something is clearly not useful, feel free to remove it.  That's my policy, anyway.