# Help me undelete Knuth's answer to a Stack Overflow question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, undelete

Here's a posting that got deleted a while back... It surprised me since it was a hand-written note from [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) himself, providing a definitive answer to a question that had been asked on Stack Overflow.

It's always seemed a shame to me that his note was deleted, even with the best of intentions. So, apropos of the podcast this morning I thought I would raise the issue and see what people thought.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126096/did-knuth-ever-refer-to-taocp-as-the-most-purchased-least-read-computer-scien

Unfortunately, only 10K users can see the posting. I've mirrored the content to my personal web site (a far less permanent site than Stack Overflow in my reckoning):

http://markharrison.net/stackoverflow/knuth

So, if anybody has a clue as to the best way to request an undelete on this, feel free to chime in!

[image]

Comment: +1 - Donald Knuth is one of the most prominent computer scientists in the world.  I say we keep it, **and lock it**.

Comment: This would be the way to request it. We can't vote to undelete it, as it was deleted by a moderator.

Comment: Given that the question only has one answer and only one vote, I'm not sure that it's worth being undeleted.  Not everything can be granted *historical status*.  I'd say that it's a great candidate for a blog post (yours), but not of real historical interest on SO.

Comment: It's not really an answer "to a question that had been asked on SO". Rather a not quite on-topic question was asked to accommodate the existing letter by Knuth.

Comment: Just in case: http://web.archive.org/web/20100702212115/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126096/did-knuth-ever-refer-to-taocp-as-the-most-purchased-least-read-computer-scienc

Comment: @sth The *question* (not a *Question*) was asked in the comments of another *Question*. This *Question* re-asked that *question* once the answer was available.

Comment: You might also want to consider donating the originals to http://www.computerhistory.org/

Comment: Please stop creating tags that are ultra-specific.  There is no reason to tag this question "knuth", as that's not a topic that is talked about frequently on meta or warrants its own tag.  You did this on your last meta post was well (with the "reposting" tag).

Comment: From now on I plan to refer to deletionists as ["Knuth haters"](http://markharrison.net/stackoverflow/knuth/)

Comment: @Michael: Indeed, deletion itself should be referred to as "the Knuth-lear option", or simply "Knuthing". As in "Knuth 'em all!".

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I read that as the "Knuth-*Lear* option" and found it to be a perfectly [runcible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runcible#Computer_science) choice.

Comment: Wait, the entire hubbub that sparked I don't know how many rants was *that question*? I don't care who wrote the note, that is not on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I clicked that link expecting to see a question with an answer posted by Donald Knuth... :/

Comment: @sth, you're not quite correct.  see the comments to Rosinante's answer where I provide the context.  The question was asked regarding TAOCP.

Comment: @casperOne, sorry.  I was doing my best according to the guidelines I knew... they seem relevant to me! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61307/on-guidelines-to-tagging-and-avoiding-unnecessary-tags . PS, Try to have a more moderate tone of voice... you're a moderator after all, not a scolder! ;-)

Comment: Really? A question gets deleted and you *immediately* play the this-is-a-personal-attack-on-Donald-Knuth card? [ಠ_ಠ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor)

Comment: @MarkTrapp, um yes... if you consider the gap between June 2010 and March 2012 "immediate".

Comment: @Mark Harrison: I think he's referring to the gap between yesterday's deletion and your posting of this meta question.

Comment: @BoltClocks a Unicorn, that was undeleted while talking to lso mods, then put back on the shelf after they confirmed they don't take technical stuff.  Mark Trapp is getting upset over nothing... what prompted this was this morning's podcast which gave the (correct?) impression that issues like this should be brought up on meta.  If that's not the proper procedure, please correct me as I requested, ok?

Comment: @MarkHarrison From your archived version, linked in your question: *Wow, It's hard to believe the Knuth-haters over on Stack Overflow deleted this.* Yes, that's exactly what happened: people who loathe Knuth set out to delete it. My god, how devious! Are the Illuminati involved as well?

Comment: @Mark Trapp, I don't know where you're going with this... if you can make it clearer as to what kind of response you're looking for I'll be happy to oblige.  If you're just showing generic pique, consider it noted... and  Shh about the Illuminati, the less they know about your Knuth hatred the better!

Comment: @MarkHarrison You really don't see anything absurd about immediately jumping to the most extreme and inflammatory rationale? Assigning malice aforethought (i.e., saying people who hate Knuth deleted the question) to a routine action is silly, not based on any evidence, and detracts from any defensible position you could've presented. All things being equal, the simplest reason (i.e., people thought the *question* —not Knuth—didn't meet the site's quality standards) tends to be the correct one.

Comment: @MarkTrapp, you're not able to see the comment thread... at the time deletion wasn't so well defined.  Marc Gravell had to send me the PDFs of the postings after they disappeared.  As I said, I was flabbergasted at the response.  And at yours as well, but I guess that's why ice cream comes in chocolate and vanilla.  Bon Appetit!

Comment: @MarkHarrison If faced with the question of "should I add a new tag?" on meta or SO, 99.999% of the time the answer is an emphatic "no". This is not part of the 0.001%. P.S. Regarding my tone: tone is subject to interpretation. If it was scolding from me, it would have been more along the lines of "**WTH were you thinking creating a new tag OMGZ**, but instead, I chose to lead with a genteel "please" and definitive, to-the-point wording. Don't confuse direct, to-the-point as scolding on my part. When I scold you, you'll know it. =)

Comment: BTW, I tried to see if [literature.se] might take it, but they don't accept questions about nonfic technical books...  Oh, and that was clear already.  NVM.

Comment: @casparOne, got it! :)

Comment: @Won't, in case I didn't express it earlier, I appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 12):

Reading through the scans and the Wayback machine, how that question was ever on topic is a mystery. As a programmer.

Yes, it was a post that happened to fall on Stack Overflow because someone's personal blog did not have enough traffic or exposure to showcase a question about a quote which lead to a photo of a hand-written Knuth note.

That's a lot of unrest because someone was using Stack Overflow as their personal blog. And not in the actual programming solution way, but as a digression or aside to things.

If anything *might* belong on Knuth's Wikipedia article.

Comment: Don't be rude.  If you're talking about me then address me directly instead of saying "someone" as if you didn't know who you were talking about.

Comment: Didn't realise who the gravatar was on the scan. Why wouldn't it be on topic on your blog then?

Comment: No worries then.  markharrison.net is used for a lot of other things (primary as a proxy server when I worked in China) but it's not a blog.  I have a stackoverflow directory where I put some images (before SO hosted images), and stuck the files there for posterity.  I'm old enough that I'm pretty sure SO will outlive me, and therefore my hosting account!

Comment: @MarkHarrison: What about Wikipedia???  It would definitely be worth its own page linked off of [the TAoCP page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming).

Comment: @Won't Wouldn't that violate [Wikipedia:No original research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:No_original_research)?

Comment: @JeremyBanks: I give up.  This won't be on topic anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Reading the comments on other answers, it seems you just want a place for it to live indefinitely that outlives your website. That cannot work on Stack Overflow. This is not the place to collect archives of great people in programming.

I have reposted the question in full on Quora for the time being. I highly believe your content is notable enough to be kept on Wikipedia under a subsection within [TAOCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) or Knuth. Please give it a try.

*[Did Knuth ever refer to TAOCP as the “most purchased, least read” computer science books?](http://www.quora.com/Donald-Knuth/Did-Knuth-ever-refer-to-TAOCP-as-the-%E2%80%9Cmost-purchased-least-read%E2%80%9D-computer-science-books)*

Answer (score 4):

Warning upvoters: I misread the historical answer, so this is a rewritten answer, and you may want to change your vote.

A note from Knuth written specifically to answer a question about something on SO sure is interesting. However, it's not a very on-topic question. I think this deserves some other presentation. It could be just a matter of applying the new 'historical interest' locking, but it seems as if it might be fun for the SO staff to have an area of the site which is material about the impact of the site on the real world, and this would make a great starting point.

Comment: I don't necessarily think it is an on-topic question, but I do believe the note _was_ written for the purpose of providing an answer here (or where ever Mark intended, as DEK replied to him). See the enlarged views on Mark's website. DEK makes notes on Mark's letter to him and comments on Pixar's "Up" (a reference to where Mark works at). The scan and hastily patched images are Mark's attempt at putting them all in one place.

Comment: Hmm, upon rereading, I see your point.

Comment: According to the archives, among the first comment was "This content is better suited to your blog, rather than Stack Overflow." Which means it was never on topic and someone's blog did not have as much traffic as SO

Comment: yoda, that's correct.  I had repeated the "most purchased, least read" quote as an answer to another question.  It had the highest number of votes for the question, so went to the top.  User @ShreevatsaR then called BS on me, asking for a source.  Because I realized that I had provided an undocumented answer that might be used by other people, I felt I had a responsibility to clear the answer up.  I knew Don slightly from some conferences we had both attended over the years, so I sent him the note asking him to clear things up, which he did.

Comment: (continued)  I felt bad about spreading something incorrect, so was very happy to be able to provide an authoritative answer to the question.  We had lunch a couple of weeks later, and I was personally thrilled that he know of SO and spoke in a rather complimentary tone about it.  So I thought that it was quite a feather in the cap of a web site *specifically devoted to computer programming* to have gotten a hand-written response from the man himself regarding a question on the site.

Comment: @random, my primary blog is about homebrew UAV systems and aerial robotics ( http://eastbay-rc.blogspot.com ), so it wouldn't be a good fit there.  As you can see from this comment in 2008 I note all my programming Q/A on SO and have been doing so for some time:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237327/oracle-how-to-upsert-update-or-insert-into-a-table#comment172773_237327